# PyDev mark occurrences not working with vrapper

Tags: pydev

This is a long shot, but I thought I would give a try.

PyDev has Mark Occurrences (just like CDT and others) and the feature works fine when I place the cursor over a word by using the standard arrow keys or the mouse.  However, I am using vrapper (a vi plugin for Eclipse) and it uses the standard vi home row keys for cursor movement (hjkl).  Mark Occurrences is not triggered by vi movement keys.

Working:

1. PyDev with regular arrow keys
2. CDT and PDE with regular arrow keys and vi keys (I haven't tested other environments)

Not working:

1. PyDev with vi keys.

So the question is -- is there a way to trigger PyDev to mark occurrences even with non-arrow keys?

Edit: clarifying the title